# Best way to have different .htaccess files for different servers?

Tags: git, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a website under source control (Git) and using two branches for two different servers. The `master` branch reflects the production website, and the `develop` branch is what’s deployed to our test server.

However, the test server is public-accessible but up until now has been protected with **.htaccess** and **.htpasswd**.

There are a lot of `RewriteRule` directives in the **.htaccess** file and wondering: what’s the best way to have both servers use the same **.htaccess** rule, but have the test site also have the **.htpassw** rules?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431006/need-different-htaccess-for-staging-and-live-site-from-git-repo

Answer (score 1):

1. **Obvious way** - different .htaccess in different branches, merge files on merge
2. **Git-style way** - smudge/clean filters, which (scripts behind filters) convert *common keyword* to final code depending from branch (and back transformation also)
3. **SCM-independent way** - shared code, which is processed by used build-deploy on delivery stage and get usable files (if websites aren't Working Directory of repos)

Comment: I’d like to be able to not have different .htaccess files, as there’s a lot of `RewriteRules`, and then `develop` gets merged into `master` when it’s production-ready.

Comment: @MartinBean - use second way in this case

Comment: I like this answer, I didn't know about smudge filters. The idea is the same as my answer with the git hooks, but uses a dedicated mechanism rather than hacking with the git hooks.

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't have any password-related information at all in a code repository.

That said, you can't really have one file be in only the develop branch and in master, assuming you merge from develop to master. You could perhaps use a git hook (possibly post-receive, depending on how your machines are set up) to remove the file when checking out master, but that is extremely brittle.

A better approach is to not have the file in git at all and rather maintaining it manually. You could have a git hook on the test server that copies the .htpasswd file from elsewhere. Or you could keep that file in a separate repository even and just symlink it in the test server's directory.

Comment: Currently I do something similar with config files, where the relavant environment’s config file is copied after a pull. Just wondered what the usual process was for protecting a test site with .htpasswd on a Git-managed site, as I can’t be the first person to do this.